# How To Make Client Certificate Authentication Optional In Azure AppServices

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have Published my WebApi on azure as AppService. In Web API some urls requires client certificate and some not. I set *certEnabled=true* in AppService using ARMClient, but It makes my other calls(non-certificate) invalid. 
When I researched on this issue, I came to know that *certEnabled=true* expects certificate for all calls.

**I want to make request using certificate on specific api urls only.**
What should I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to make request using certificate on specific api urls only. What should I do.

Unfortuntly ,it is not supported on the Azure WebApp currently. I also find a [similar feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/19356307-enable-client-certificate-authentication-per-dir) that is underview by azure team. And [optional client certificates for TLS mutual auth](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/13481457-support-optional-client-certificates-for-tls-mutua) is also not supported now.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I have found is to allow both http and https, and then, in the code, filter which requests you accept on http.